# Откуда взялся зазор между Toolbar и RelativeLayout внутри LinearLayout?

Tags: android, toolbar

Есть такая разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".cityActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base.AppBarOverlay">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:openDrawer="start">


            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context=".cityActivity"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:id="@+id/searchLayout">
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
                        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                        android:hint="Название города"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/list"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
                    android:divider="@color/divider"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
                </ListView>

            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_city2"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_city2_drawer" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

В предпросмотре видим зазор между тулбаром и RelativeLayout с EditText'ом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На устройстве зазор еще больше. Исследовал все что мог, без вашей помощи не обойтись.

UPD

А в следующем активити, там, где я не использую шторку или CoordinatorLayout, или виджет AppBarLayout все нормально:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.qwerq.qwerq.sferaActivity"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etSearch"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:hint="Название категории"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Для android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Используйте `app:elevation="0dp"`

вместо `android:elevation="0dp"`

Comment: сработало app:elevation="0dp" для android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Answer (score 2):

Это тень от тулбара, поставьте ему elevation="0dp"

Comment: Не помогло. Я обновил вопрос. Добавил скриншот и разметку следующего активити, в котором я не использую шторку. Там все нормально.

Comment: сработало app:elevation="0dp" для android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout