# DrawerLayout под AppBarLayout. Откуда взялся зазор?

Tags: android, toolbar, drawerlayout

В своем [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567129/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-toolbar-%D0%B8-relativelayout-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-linearlayout/567355#567355) я интересовался, как убрать зазор между тулбаром и LinearLayout. Добрые люди подсказали, что нужно установить у  AppBArLayout app:elevation="0dp" , и проблема решилась. Но беда не приходит одна, и вот теперь, после того, как DrawerLayout спустилось под Toolbar - у нас новый зазор, размерами куда больше, чем тень от чего бы то ни было:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И это, заметьте, шаблон Android Studio со шторкой, в который еще не успели внести изменения, кроме как спустить шторку под toolbar.

```
activity_main.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ru.qwerq.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ru.qwerq.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Что это и как с этим бороться?

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? Зачем вы поменяли разметку?

Comment: Хотим, чтобы при выдвигании шторки не закрывался toolbar

Comment: Вообще раньше всё это так и работало, но потом гугл решил, что надо закрывать тулбар. Так что вам придётся изгаляться. Попробуйте, для начала, поставить для NavigationView отрицательный margin какой-нибудь, вернув разметку к изначальному виду

Comment: Не помогло. Вообще-то настораживает то, что эта полоса по высоте равна области уведомлений вверху экрана и цветом в primary_dark, как и область уведомлений. Если представить что шторка занимает весь экран, значит область уведомлений накладывается на нее, а цвет этой полоски соответствует цвету области уведомлений для того, чтобы цвет области уведомлений не менялся. Так? если так, то мне кажется саму шторку ковырять нужно. Вернулись к рекомендациям Гугла, оставим шторку как есть, поверх тулбара.

Comment: Да, это очень похоже на статусБар. Скорее всего гугл вписах какой-то аццкий хак для того, чтобы левое меню одинаково выглядело на разных версиях. Так что да - лучше стандартное поведение оставить. Хотя, может быть, помогут манипуляции с `translusentStatusBar` атрибутом в стилях. Но лучше туда не лезть - там всё плохо с обратной совместимостью

Comment: Я так и думал. Спасибо Вам за участие!

Comment: Вопрос можно считать закрытым